# Customize Tiles in Android GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I want to create a Grid in my home page application, where I can add and remove tiles like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyiwU.png)

My problem is that I don't know how to create the "Add new service tile" and move its position every time I add a new tile.
Any ideas?

Comment: use recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a list of ItemTypes. The last item in your list should always be the ADD_NEW_ITEM_TYPE. Any new item that is added by the user should be added to your list on the second last position.

Whenever such an addition is made, just `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemInserted(position)`